# PYQT file convertor in a gui. Button not working with convertor

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a GUI file convertor and able to convert files using the terminal and my script, but now trying to enable this with a few buttons.  So far GUI will take the directory, append to the list, but when I hit the convert button, they dont get used in the script.

```
def convertor():
    # process all non-master CSVs
    for fileLocated in os.listdir(directoryPath):
        if fileLocated.endswith(".csv") and 'master' not in fileLocated.lower():

            csvFilename = fileLocated
            strippedFileName =  os.path.splitext(csvFilename)[0]
            wavFileName =  directoryPath  + strippedFileName + ".wav"

            print strippedFileName
            cutOff = re.compile(r"(([0-9]{8})?.*_[Tt]r-[0-9]+)_?(?:([0-9]+)mph)?.*")
            allGroups = cutOff.search(strippedFileName).groups()
            result = cutOff.search(strippedFileName)
            xmlBaseFileName = result.group(1)
            if result.group(2) is not None: # try to get date of delivery from filename
                dateDelivery = "%s/%s/%s" % (result.group(2)[0:2], result.group(2)[2:4], result.group(2)[4:8])
            else:
                dateDelivery = 'n/a'
                print 'Could not parse date received from filename'
            if result.group(3) is not None: # try to get mph from filename
                mph = result.group(3)
            else:
                mph = 'n/a/'
                print 'Could not parse mph from filename'

            csvFilename = directoryPath + csvFilename
            csvFile = open(csvFilename, 'rU')

            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

            postProcTags = ["startTime", "endTime", "transcription", "signalQuality", "startSession", "endSession"]

            metaDataObj = metaDataCreator.MetaData()

            for row in csvReader:
                sampleNode = etree.Element("Sample")
                if "literalPrompt" in row and row["literalPrompt"].strip() != '':
                    promptNode = etree.Element("Prompt")
                    promptNode = metaDataCreator.createPromptNode(*[(tagName, row[tagName]) for tagName in row.keys() if tagName not in postProcTags and tagName != 'order'])
                    sampleNode.append(promptNode)
                if "transcription" in row and row["transcription"].strip() != '':

                    postProcNode = etree.Element("postProc")
                    postProcNode = metaDataCreator.createPostProcNode(*[row[postProcTag] for postProcTag in postProcTags])
                    sampleNode.append(postProcNode)

                metaDataObj.addSamplePair(sampleNode)

                    #print etree.tostring(sampleNode, pretty_print=True)

            metaDataObj.createSpeakerNode(gender="Male") # (speakerId='80', gender="Female", ageGroupMin="40", ageGroupMax="49", nativeSpeaker="True")
            metaDataObj.createAudioNode(filePath=wavFileName)
            metaDataObj.createSessionNode(speed=mph, subDomain='biking')
            metaDataObj.createGeneralNode(originalFileName=xmlBaseFileName, dateOfDelivery=dateDelivery, dateOfProcessing='%s/%s/%s' % (date.today().month, date.today().day, date.today().year))
            metaDataObj.createHardwareSetupNode(micType='n/a', bikeUnit='311', micAngle='n/a')






            tree = etree.ElementTree(metaDataObj.root)
            outputFilename = csvFilename.replace(".csv", ".xml")

            tree.write(outputFilename, pretty_print=True)
```

etc..

then ..

```
class pageTwo(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300,300,800,600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Convertor")
        self.setStyleSheet("font-size:15px")

        self.buttonConvert = QtGui.QPushButton('Convert!', self)
        self.buttonConvert.move(350, 350)
        self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convert)

        self.buttonSelect = QtGui.QPushButton('Select Files', self)
        self.buttonSelect.move(135, 200)
        self.buttonSelect.clicked.connect(self.get_in_filename)


    def get_in_filename(self):
        """Ask user for the input filename."""
        self.listWidget.clear()
        directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                           "Pick a folder")

        if directory:
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory): 
                self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)  



    def get_out_filename(self):
        pass



    def convert(self, directory):
        global convertor
        """Execute the conversion."""

        for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
            if os.listdir(directory):

                convertor(file_name)
                self.listWidgetcomplete.addItem(file_name)
```

I know I probably posted too much code on here :(  Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: How does your `convert()` function look like? You connect it to a button with: `self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convert)`, but I can't see the definition.

Comment: def convert(self, directory):
        global convertor
        """Execute the conversion."""

        for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
            if os.listdir(directory):

                convertor(file_name)
                self.listWidgetcomplete.addItem(file_name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your convert function has a parameter `directory` which specifies the directory to operate on.  But you are calling the convert function via:

```
   self.buttonConvert.clicked.connect(self.convert)
```

The `clicked` signal does pass a parameter.  But it's a Boolean.  So you are trying to "convert" True or False, not the directory you want.  This is raising an exception but the PyQt signal slot mechanism is swallowing the exception.

You need to find a different way to get the directory to the convert slot.  For example convert could read it from a member variable.  Or the list widget.